Looking for a film about a youth who gets cut off from his family and goes off to Italy
I'm looking for a movie, basically here's how the story goes:
Parents cut their kid off and give him some money to start off with. Instead, he books a flight to Italy and meets an Italian guy who is the king of (some Italian town) on the plane.  He ends up getting his passport stolen while sleeping over at a U.S. embassy employee's house. Her husband kicks him out and takes him to the town the king character lives in.  Basically he meets a girl, works in a pasta shop, etc etc. He finds himself working and being happy. 
In the end they yell (potentially offensive):

 CLUSTER FUCK


Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When di you watch it? What time was it likely from? What country was it likely from? Any other plot details or descriptions you remember? And with "king" do you actually mean a mayor or something like that?

Whaddya know? It's real!
AmeriQua (2013) aka Eurotrapped

AmeriQua is the story of a lazy recent graduate, Charlie (Bobby
  Kennedy), whose rich parents cut him off with a $5000 check and an
  ultimatum to start a life of independence and responsibility. Instead,
  he buys a plane ticket to Italy, gets robbed upon arrival and winds up
  in Bologna in the care of his new friend Lele (Lele Gabellone), the
  self-proclaimed King of Bologna, who lives with a scraggly
  punkabbestia, Ballo (Gianlucca Bazzoli), and the insatiable prostitute
  frequenter, Il Pisa (Giuseppe Sanfelice). In Bologna, Lele teaches
  Chrlie the subtle strategies that the King knows so well, namely
  hitting on Italian women, throwing all-night parties and inciting
  general anarchy. Charlie takes to it like a pro and in the process
  meets the dangerously beautiful Valentina (Alessandra Mastronardi) and
  all-American Jessica (Eva Amurri). It may have been a simple story of
  cultural exchange had Charlie not accidentally pissed off two vicious
  mafia bosses, Don Ferracane (Giancarlo Giannini) and Don Farina
  (Ernesto Mahieux) in his wanderings. What chance does a timid American
  kid, who doesn't speak Italian and hangs out with sloppy Italian party
  hounds, have against the dark forces of organized crime in Italy?

And apparently the word "clusterf***" is used A LOT, and they chant "clusterf***" at the end. According to the subtitles.
